# Get matching checksums between Java and C#

Tags: java, c#, checksum, sha256

I am porting a method that creates a checksum for a file (base64 encoded) from a C# application to Java.  In C#, this is the method:

```
public static string GetChecksum(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
      var sha = new SHA256Managed();
      byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
      return BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
    }
}
```

Here is what I have in Java so far, but it's definitely not matching the value returned from C#:

```
private static String getCheckSum(String base64Data) throws Exception {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(base64Data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] enc = md.digest();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : enc) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }

        return sb.toString().replace("-", "").toUpperCase();
    }
```

I've tried not having the charset in the `getBytes()` method, I've tried with the charset `US-ASCII`.

This stuff is not in my wheelhouse and I'm not sure how to proceed.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: string.getBytes won't help you. It will get the byte values of each single character in the string (using the chosen character encoding, in your case UTF-8). It will not decode the Base64 string. I don't know about Java, but browse the JDK documentation for some class/method that does base64-decoding...

Comment: @elgonzo . ok, let me try using the base64 decoder.   I'll report back in a few.  Thanks.

Comment: @elgonzo, ... that worked.  Thanks!  So, you commented first with the info needed to solve problem, then a bunch of other people did soon after.  It's a little embarrassing I didn't realize this on my own, but... you want to make your comment an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Since there is already an answer with regard to Base64-decoding in Java, i feel i don't need to add another duplicate answer to the mix ;-) If one of the answers addresses and solves your problem, feel free to accept it. I don't mind not getting any reputation points... ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo, cool.  Nonetheless, you being first to act will forever be enshrined in the comments :)  F them reputation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java to decode Base64 String you have this (since Java8) :

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);
String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);
```

from : https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-encode-and-decode

Comment: `new String(decodedBytes)` is not appropriate when the decoded bytes are truly binary and not textual data (and if it would be appropriate, it would be better to explicitly specify a character set).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guava library to compute hash.

```
String sha256hex = Hashing.sha256()
  .hashString(originalString, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
  .toString();
```

Apache commons codec also has library to compute hash.

```
String sha256hex = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(originalString);
```